# Set length limits to specific character class parts in Unicode regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Below my regual expression:

```
preg_match('/^[\p{L}\p{N} @]+$/u', $string);
```

My goal is set minimum and maximum length of `\p{L}`, `\p{N}`, `@` and the whole string. I tried to putting `{min, max}` after `\p{L}` and after each part but it doesn't work.

Comment: what's your requitrements?

Comment: @AvinashRaj \p{L}, \p{N}, @ and the whole string must have a minimum and a maximum length.

Comment: Like `preg_match('/^[\p{L}\p{N} @]{1,100}$/u', $string);`? Or do you want to set specific limits for letters and numbers?

Comment: @stribizhev yes, your regex checks the minimum and a maximum length of whole string, I need also to check the minimum and a maximum length of \p{L} and \p{N} and @. For example, at least two letters (\p{L}) and max 5, at least five numbers (\p{N}) and max six and finally at least three '@'.

Comment: @stribizhev exactly, I want to set specific limits for letters and numbers (and @).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the min and max length to a pattern with the help of limiting quantifiers *right after* the subpattern that you need to repeat.

Here we need to use a trick to make sure we can count non-consecutive subpatterns. It can be done with negative character classes and look-aheads in the beginning.

Here is an example of the regex for *at least 4 letters `\p{L}`, at least 5 and 6 max numbers `\p{N}`, and at least three `@`:

```
^(?=(?:[^\n\p{L}]*\p{L}){4}[^\n\p{L}]*$)(?=(?:[^\n\p{N}]*\p{N}){5,6}[^\n\p{N}]*$)(?=(?:[^\n@]*@){3}[^\n@]*$)[\p{L}\p{N} @]+$
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sC8cK3/1)

Note that `\n` can be removed if you are not planning to use multiline mode (`m` flag).

The 3 conditions are inside look-aheads:

- `(?=(?:[^\n\p{L}]*\p{L}){4}[^\n\p{L}]*$)` - This lookahead matches (from the beginning of input string) any sequence that is not letters and then a letter 4 times (you may set any other limits here, and then looks for non-letters up to the end (if it finds more, it fails).
- `(?=(?:[^\n\p{N}]*\p{N}){5,6}[^\n\p{N}]*$)` - a similar lookahead, but now, we are matching non-digits + a digit 5 or 6 times, and make sure there are no numbers later.
- `(?=(?:[^\n@]*@){3}[^\n@]*$)` - same logic for `@`.

If you need to only set a minimum threshold, you do not need those negated character classes at the end of a lookahead, e.g. `(?=(?:[^\n@]*@){3})` will match 3 or more `@`, it will just require 3 `@`s.